# LoginKey 1.25 sdk vs 2.0rc1

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

I've been trying to create an app that can run seperate from Rally.  I figured out how to use the LoginKey, but I ran into an issue when I upgraded to 2.0rc1 and now it no longer works.

Before I had:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.25/sdk.js?loginKey=secret></script>
```

Now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js?loginKey=secret></script>
```

Any ideas why the it works for 1.25 not 2.0rc1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login key is no longer supported as of SDK 2.0. We are thinking of how we will support this use case in the future but right now we do not have a replacement technology to help you.

Our current plans are to ship a new authorization API in the next few months so that we can support embedding our products into Wikis.

Comment: For what it is worth, this is a major impediment to moving to (and bothering to learn) SDK2.0. The majority of what I have created for my company are information radiators, reports, dashboards, etc. that run outside of Rally (on the Intranet, in Confluence, on wallboards, etc.) This means that since WSAPIv1.43 is depricated and will not be supported after 6/20/14, I have from whenever Rally solves the SDK2.0 external problem until 6/20/14 to rewrite all of these apps - and time keeps ticking, with no ETA from Rally.....

Comment: 6/20/14 will not be the death of your Apps. We will try to keep new Apps from being made on that old version of the SDK but everything will still be working after that date. Our current plan is to let customers using old version know via email well before we kill anything off

Answer (score 1):

LoginKey functionality predates AppSDK2. You may use it with AppSDK 1.33 and below.

There are WS API features introduced in version of WS API above 1.33. If you need to access them in your AppSDK 1.x app, you may specify a WS API version beyond that point by using a syntax below, as long as the version you use is under v2.0:

```
rallyDataSource.setApiVersion("1.43");
```

while the javascript src points to 1.33:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.33/sdk.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, unfortunately all my code is in 2.0 or later.